# Upgrading to 11.4.6 causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.docx4j.fonts.IdentityPlusMapper

Tags: docx4j

Case:
Writing a docx as pdf using `WordprocessingMLPackage` and setting the fontMapper using `IdentityPlusMapper()` from `org.docx4j.fonts` to map the fonts in the document we receive:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.docx4j.fonts.IdentityPlusMapper`

at: [getFontMapper()](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/8fc2ce124cc6f8e027b1486493b418843174490e/docx4j-core/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/WordprocessingMLPackage.java#L375)

This happens after upgrading from docx4j `11.2.8` to `11.4.6`.

Dependencies in usage are:

```
org.docx4j:docx4j-core:11.4.6
org.docx4j:docx4j-export-fo:11.4.6
org.docx4j:docx4j-JAXB-ReferenceImpl:11.4.6
```

Is this a known issue already?

Looking forward to a possible reply!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works for me.   Do you have a module-info.java in your project, and compare https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/VERSION_11_4_6/docx4j-samples-docx-export-fo/src/main/java/module-info.java

Comment: @JasonPlutext No, I don't have it. I have the exact problem as the answer below. 
Additional info: I just tried the minor release too 11.4.7. It didn't help as the same issue is occurring.

Answer (score 1):

This assertion error is appearing from the static block of the IdentityPlusMapper or the BestMatchingMapper whatever we use. The exact line is:

```
PhysicalFonts.discoverPhysicalFonts();
```

The fix of the problem is to restrict fonts loading before the static block using font selection regex as stated in the javadoc of:

```
PhysicalFonts.setRegex()
```

The following way quickly solved the problem along with that it reduces memory utilization and the static block's execution time:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                            .load(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()));
String fontRegex = ".*(Courier New|Arial|Times New Roman|Comic Sans|Georgia|Impact|Lucida Console|Lucida Sans Unicode|Palatino Linotype|Tahoma|Trebuchet|Verdana|Symbol|Webdings|Wingdings|MS Sans Serif|MS Serif).*";
                    
if(System.getProperty("os.name").startsWith("Windows")) {
  fontRegex = ".*(calibri|cour|arial|times|comic|georgia|impact|LSANS|pala|tahoma|trebuc|verdana|symbol|webdings|wingding).*";
}
PhysicalFonts.setRegex(fontRegex);
wordMLPackage.setFontMapper(new BestMatchingMapper());
Docx4J.toPDF(wordMLPackage, outputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a font loading problem. I'm on a Mac (latest Monterey) and I'm getting the same exception in the contructor call:

```kotlin
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting code not to raise a throwable but caught
  java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.complexscripts.fonts.GlyphPositioningTable$DeviceTable.<init>(GlyphPositioningTable.java:1778)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.complexscripts.fonts.OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.readPosDeviceTable(OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.java:1729)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.complexscripts.fonts.OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.readPosAnchor(OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.java:2053)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.complexscripts.fonts.OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.readMarkToLigaturePosTableFormat1(OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.java:2347)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.complexscripts.fonts.OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.readMarkToLigaturePosTable(OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.java:2373)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.complexscripts.fonts.OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.readGPOSSubtable(OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.java:3124)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.complexscripts.fonts.OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.readLookupTable(OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.java:3193)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.complexscripts.fonts.OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.readLookupList(OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.java:3220)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.complexscripts.fonts.OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.readCommonLayoutTables(OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.java:3241)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.complexscripts.fonts.OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.readGPOS(OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.java:3501)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.complexscripts.fonts.OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.readAll(OTFAdvancedTypographicTableReader.java:88)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.fonts.truetype.OpenFont.handleCharacterSpacing(OpenFont.java:895)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.fonts.truetype.OpenFont.readFont(OpenFont.java:867)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.fonts.truetype.OFFontLoader.read(OFFontLoader.java:121)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.fonts.truetype.OFFontLoader.read(OFFontLoader.java:105)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.fonts.FontLoader.getFont(FontLoader.java:130)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.fonts.FontLoader.loadFont(FontLoader.java:114)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.fop.fonts.autodetect.FontInfoFinder.find(FontInfoFinder.java:262)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts.getPhysicalFont(PhysicalFonts.java:307)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts.addPhysicalFonts(PhysicalFonts.java:246)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts.addPhysicalFont(PhysicalFonts.java:236)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.PhysicalFonts.discoverPhysicalFonts(PhysicalFonts.java:183)
    at org.docx4j.fonts.IdentityPlusMapper.<clinit>(IdentityPlusMapper.java:74)
    at foo(...)

open fun foo(...) {
    ...
    val mlPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(ByteArrayInputStream(input))
    mlPackage.fontMapper = IdentityPlusMapper() //<-- boom
}
```

Update (August 29th 2022): I fixed the issue by upgrading Docx4j to 11.4.7 . Additionally I had to add the following code before the call to `Docx4J.toFO(...)`:

```kotlin
val fopFactoryBuilder: FopFactoryBuilder = FORendererApacheFOP.getFopFactoryBuilder(foSettings)
FORendererApacheFOP.getFOUserAgent(foSettings, fopFactoryBuilder.build())
```

Comment: Your answer does not really help solving the original issue.

Comment: I realize it doesn't. I'm adding context to "works for me" by providing stack trace of the problem. I can't add it to the original post unfortunately.

Comment: @GeorgBerky thanks for this, its helpful.  See now https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-3062

Comment: @JasonPlutext, thank you. This issue seems to be related. I'm also on an M1 Mac. The font might not be the same, but it seems to be a general problem with the fonts.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the same by setting regex for fonts available in Mac which's recommened by PhysicalFonts class set regex method as well.

```
           PhysicalFonts.regex = ".*(Courier New|Arial|Times New Roman|Comic Sans|Georgia|Impact|Lucida Console|Lucida Sans Unicode|Palatino Linotype|Tahoma|Trebuchet|Verdana|Symbol|Webdings|Wingdings|MS Sans Serif|MS Serif).*"
```